# SQL How To Get Columns where sub columns has the given value?

Tags: sql

I have Orders table and each order has order entries that contain products. Now I'm trying to get orders where if any OrderEntryModel.PRODUCT is not null in the order. For hours of searching I couldn't find any solution. Is this possible to get this with a query?

Comment: This is a good resource for improving your SQL questions. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Cliff notes: 1.) Tag your DBMS. 2.) Sample Data and Expected Result in well formatted text (no images).

Comment: What is a "sub column"?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I simply don't understand:  "trying to get orders where if any OrderEntryModel.PRODUCT is not null in the order. "

Comment: Ok to be more spesific, for example I have 3 orders and these orders have 3 entries. So I have 9 entries. 1.order / 1.Entry - 2. Entry - 3. Entry, 2.order / 1.Entry - 2. Entry - 3. Entry , 3.order / 1.Entry - 2. Entry - 3. Entry. Entry is another table that depend order table. So entry has some attributes, pk, code etc. Let's say that 2. orders 3. entry code equals to 5000. I need to get the orders where in any entry has code equals to 5000 in that order. So if I can select this, the result will be nothing but the second order.

Comment: What if 3. orders 1. entry's code also equals to 5000, the result would be 2. & 3. orders.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for EXISTS, but your question is lacking the details I mentioned in the comment.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Order_ ord1
 WHERE EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM Order_ ord2 -- Or if you have a separate product table (can't tell from question)
            WHERE ord2.product IS NOT NULL
              AND ord1.orderID = ord2.orderID
         );
```